# Generating single page HTML JavaDoc

Tags: java, javadoc

I want to generate a single HTML file from all Java source files of a project. Generally, JavaDoc generates multiple HTML pages linked together, but I want to have everything in one page. Is that possible?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have them on different pages but linked via an index page?

Comment: I want to upload it on a wiki page, so I wanted it to be on a single page with links to different location on the page itself.

Comment: Even I want upload it to my wikipage !!! Pleas help @Expressions_Galore

Comment: Did you check the answer? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I was able to get a PDF out of my JavaDoc using [PDF Doclet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfdoclet/).